# How does the formal definition of O(n) tie to simple explanation in data structures class

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, big-o

The informal idea of Big-O is described as "it's the highest order of growth of a function" ie f(n) = 3n^2 + 5n + 50 is just O(n^2).

I do understand that Big-O is just a way of saying "guaranteed to not be worse than this period". Formally, it appears the definition is f(n) -> O(g(n)) iff f(n) <= c * g(n) where c is positive

First some mathy stuff.. if f(n) = 5n^2, g(n)=n I should be able to show 5n^2 isn't O(g(n)) by doing

```
5n^2 <= cn
5n <= c
```

If the idea is that is that c isn't a constant(I have no idea if that's a requirement), and that is proof f(n) isnt in O(g(n)), what about if g(n) were n^3 (of which it surely should be contained)?

```
5n^2 <= cn^3
5/n <= c
```

I have a misunderstanding of how the math works out for all of this I assume, so I ask:

How does all this fancy stuff work

How does it connect to the simple definition given in my data structures class?

Thanks for any help

Comment: C is is "some constant" - it must be *independent* of n.

Comment: That doesn't help in the case of g(n)=n^3 example though. simplified c = 5/n is dependent on n right? but 5n^2 surely is O(n^3) (its bound is lower and should therefore encompass this as well)?

Comment: See definition [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Comment: `c`, in the definition of Big-O, is an *arbitrarily* chosen constant. Basically, for a function `g(n)` to belong to `O(f(n))`, there must be some value, *any constant value* for `c` such that `g(n) < c * f(n)`

Comment: It's about providing a bound on the behavior as `n` goes to infinity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`n` is a positive integer, which means that `1<=n` and therefore `5/n<=5/1=5`, so you can pick `c=5`.

A more complete definition also allows you to pick `n0` and `a`, both constants, and only prove that `f(n)<=a+c*g(n)` for all `n0<n`

Comment: I like how you didnt beat around the bush and made the direct comparison to n^3. Is there some proof that there's always some c that applies to the simpler definition given in my class? I don't really care to see it, I'm just curious why they would dumb it down so greatly.

Comment: The definitions are almost equivalent - there are some end-cases. For example - `f(n)=n` and `g(n)=n^2-n`. When `n=1`, `g(1)=1^2-1=1-1=0` while `f(1)=1`. No matter what `c` you pick you will never get `f(1)<=c*g(1)`, since that is equivalent to `1<=c*0=0`. The extended definitions allows us to choose `n0=1`(and then `2<=n`) or `a=1`(and then `1<=1+c*0=1+0=1`). The extended definition is more useful in mathematics - in CS you can usually assume `0<g(n)`, and in that case - the definitions are equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`c` is a constant (i.e. independent of `n`)

In your first example (it's proof by contradiction):
i.e. assume

```
5n^2 <= cn
5n <= c
```

But for any fixed constant c, we can find a value of n that makes it untrue.

For example pick c = 1000000, then a value of n = 200001 would be a contradiction.

In your second example, we know that f(n) is O(n^2), therefore it is also O(n^3) and above. If you are bounded by k(n^2), you are also bounded by j(n^3)

Answer (score 0):

> The informal idea of Big-O is described as "it's the highest order of growth of a function" ie f(n) = 3n^2 + 5n + 50 is just O(n^2).

I wouldn't say that this is the idea behind Big-O. Informally Big-O is some rough estimation of what a given function cannot exceed. And it's usage is mostly approximating how something will grow for big numbers.

For example, if we take a 6 digit number, we can definitely say that it's less than million without looking for its digits. There are a lot of cases when this is enough and we don't need to analyse all digits.

For analysing function growth two factors play their role:

1. we only interested in function behaviour for very large numbers
2. if `f` is bigger than `g`, but we can fix it with multiplying `g` by some big constant, that's means `f`'s advantage is not because of growth

This leads us to two parts of the definition: (1) some constant and (2) for big enough n

And for polynomials indeed, the higher order component defines grow speed.